# たしかに and かもしれない in one sentence

Tags: translation

I've encountered sentences like this several times:

たしかに村での戦闘の直接の原因はその……ギアが不時着したことかもしれない

The literal translation would be: "Certainly, the direct cause of the battle in the village might be......that Gear that made an emergency landing". But it doesn't make sense. It's either "certainly" or "might be". How should I translate this?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could provide some context. At least a few sentences before/after would be great.

Comment: How does that not make sense?  Don't you say "There is certainly a possibility that ~~." in your language?  Is that certain or just possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「確かに」 can be used (often in colloquial speech) to mean "It is true that..., (but...)" (≂「確かに～だけれど...」) "You're right, ..." "You may be right, ..." "Indeed, ..." (≂「あぁ、確かに、...」「なるほど、...」)  or "Now that you mention it..." (≂「確かに、言われてみれば（その通り）、...」)

> たしかに村での戦闘の直接の原因はその……ギアが不時着したことかもしれない

"*You're right, / Now that you mention it, / It is true that* the direct cause of the battle in the village might be......that Gear made an emergency landing."

Answer (score 1):

Though it doesn't make sense in English, but it is used in Japanese. I think it is used when a speaker has a confidence in the guess.

For example, 確かに彼はそう言ったかもしれない.

And I found some examples in a dictionary, which are 確かにいるかも知れないな(Certainly there might), 確かに、顔は隠せるかもしれない(It might indeed be possible to cover my face.).